# How to query the item with lowest timestamp from a string[]

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `string[] files` containing a couple of filenames in this format:

For example:

```
// my string[]
john_q1_1527421201.csv
john_q1_1527421202.csv
john_q1_1527421203.csv
```

**Note: The latest value is a valid timestamp**

How can I quickly use LINQ to query the filename with the lowest timestamp?

```
public string GetOldestCsvFile(string[] files)
{
     ...
     // implementation here
     ...
}
```

#### edit 1

```
// my string[]
john_q1_1527421034.csv
john_q1_1527421035.csv
john_q1_1527421034.csv

public void GetOldestCsvFile(string[] files)
{
    var timestamp = files.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Replace("john_q1_", string.Empty).Replace(".csv", string.Empty))).OrderBy(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine(timestamp); // <-- it never reaches this line
}
```

I'd like it to return the lowest timestamp in terms of the one with the oldest date. So that would be `john_q1_1527421034.csv`

Comment: What have you tried? There are many previous similar questions about sorting string by part of the strings

Comment: john_q1 is always the same, yes!, the only thing that varies is the timestamp, this is generated from a `Python 3`-script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OrderBy because the files share the same name, the only different part being the timestamp.

```
var lowestTimeStamp = files.OrderBy(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
```

Without alphanumeric sorting, we can replace the unnecessary fields and parsing to integers.

```
  var timestamp = files.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Replace("john_q1_", string.Empty).Replace(".csv", string.Empty))).OrderBy(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: That just orders on the file names.

Comment: I don't need to order  it, I need to achieve the timestamp with the lowest date

Comment: Could you explain the difference between the first and the second one? (Besides, it returns an error: `Input string was not in a correct format.`). The first line returns a valid  `int`

Comment: The second example takes in consideration the question exposed by @mjwills.

Comment: I just tested the code and it works. Can you please show us what you have written so far?

Comment: How do you call GetOldestCsvFile?

Comment: I am calling this method in a `OnPostAsync`-function within my `.NET MVVM`-application, this function only executes this `GetOldestCsvfile()`